# What should be the partition scheme for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have a Dell Vostro 3446 laptop (x64) with 500gb HDD, 4 GB RAM and Intel Core i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz.

I am installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and no other operating system. [No Dual Boot]

I want to run java programs and c++ programs and I also want to store files like movies, music and pictures.

What should be the best partition scheme?

Thank You

Comment: "should"? There is no mandatory partition scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Where you're installing Ubuntu in single boot, you only have one storage device (HDD), you don't have any specific needs related to partitions, and I assume you're a beginner Linux user, use the default partitioning scheme to keep things simple.

Comment: I concur...keep it simple. There's no need to make lots of partitions unless you intend to reinstall Ubuntu with each new version and keep your configuration settings. Personally I prefer a clean system so when I moved from 12.04 - 14.04 - 16.04 - 18.04 I just backed up my files and wiped the drive. I have just one partition for Kubuntu and one for Windows on my main SSD in dual boot. I also have a NAS with RAID 10 for main long term storage & backup on my gigabit network with UPS backup.

Comment: @Compatico Even if you want to reinstall it, the installer can keep your home directory intact - no need for a separate `/home` partition.

Comment: I'm aware...but I like to keep it pure. I wipe and put in a clean system with each LTS release. I've done it so many times, I could wipe my Kubuntu partition tonight and in about half an hour I'd be up and running agin with the install and configure with my widgets and settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plan ahead (for future new installs) the easiest way would be:

```
/
/home
/{personal_partition}
```

You keep /home/ as empty as can be (see `.config/user-dirs.dirs` on changing your directories. The 3rd partition you use for all your personal data (movies, audio, coding). It can also hold a copy of all your DEBs and widgets and other stuff you use a lot.

- A reinstall with wiping all settings = format / and /home and mount personal_partition.
- A reinstall and not wiping personal settings = format / and mount of /home and  personal_partition.
- A full wipe (when selling your system) = format /,/home and personal_partition.